# Pandas Conditional Vlookup Loop

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have one data frame that I want to use as a cross-reference to fill missing values of the "Business" field of the main data frame.

**xref**

```
  Material Type Business
 0  XXX           111
 1  YYY           222
 2  ZZZ           333
```

**main**

```
Material Type   Business
0   XXX     
1   YYY          222
2   ZZZ
```

I know I can "merge" both datasets together but this will duplicate the Business column and I'll have to write some clean-up code.  What I'm interested in is a simple looping lambda function.  That loops through the elements maybe on list/dictionary item position.  Any ideas on how to write this?

Comment: What do you expect as output?

Comment: `main.update(xref)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `combine_first`:

```
>>> main.combine_first(xref)
  Material Type  Business
0           XXX     111.0
1           YYY     222.0
2           ZZZ     333.0
```

Comment: this worked quite elegantly!  i first had to index my actual tables to same index so code version i ended up using was main.set_index('material type').combine_first(xref)

Answer (score 0):

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> xref = pd.DataFrame({"material": ["XXX", "YYY", "ZZZ"], "business": [111, 222, 333]})
>>> main = pd.DataFrame({"material": ["XXX", "YYY", "ZZZ"], "business": [None, 222, None]})
>>> xref
  material  business
0      XXX       111
1      YYY       222
2      ZZZ       333
>>> main
  material  business
0      XXX       NaN
1      YYY     222.0
2      ZZZ       NaN
```

You can just index the `xref` dataframe by its material column, and then set the correct business for every entry in `main` all at once:

```
>>> main["business"] = xref.set_index("material")["business"].loc[main["material"]].values
>>> main
  material  business
0      XXX       111
1      YYY       222
2      ZZZ       333
```

Comment: got ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index. both of the fields in question contain string values.